# How to find outbound references from class

Tags: c#, roslyn

Iam trying to move a class. As a result the scope changes. And I want to check outbound references from a class and replace them according to new scope.

```
namespace ns{

   class ContainingClass{
      public static int someCounter=0;

      class InnerClass{
         public static void func(){
            someCounter++;
         }
      }

   }

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically? Can you give an example of what you want to happen?

Comment: @DavidPoeschl I am trying to do this programmatically as a refactoring. I move inner class to outer container. It may be accessing conaining class members so i have to fully qualify names. 
Is there a way given a ISymbol and position/node  to generate memberAccessSyntax to reference that symbol?

Comment: I don't understand, your code wouldn't compile. Is `someCounter` meant to be `static`?

Comment: Sorry for that. Yes it is static.